# Show icons in Windows explorer toolbar in Windows 7 or 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, icons

I want to show icons for every options in Windows Explorer toolbar. Like when we select any folder then icon for `Open` option displays but other options like `New folder`,`Share with` have no icons. How can I enable icons for other options there?

[image]

Comment: As I know, there are no standart methods... But there can be some settings in Windows Registry which can do it.

Comment: @Jet : You are right. I have already added `Copy path` `Hide selected itmes` etc. options but not able to find so that I can display icons for them.

Comment: And where is that registry path? tell me, I want to dig it too :)

Comment: If you want to add new commands then : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksNoItemsSelected` and if you wants to see available commands : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell`. I am using Windows 8 and to enable toolbar in Explorer you need to disable Ribbon Bar using third party tool.

Comment: OK, I am starting to research it. I will write here if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is removed since Vista. Install [ClassicShell](http://www.classicshell.net/) to get a toolbar with icons back:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. I was asking about the bar which is below Address Bar.

Comment: as I said, this doesn't works any longer. You need a 3rd party solution like ClassicShell (that's why it is named this way to bring old feature of the classic Win95 Interface back).